# syntax for css selector class attribute combination

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, css-selectors

I have bunch of elements with class X.

some elements have class Y also (ie both X and Y)

how do I select set of elements only have X **with partial class name**?

below is my example HTML

```
<td class="dxeCalendarDay_Office2010Blue dxeCalendarOtherMonth_Office2010Blue" savedcursor="[object Object]" style="cursor: pointer;">29</td>

<td class="dxeCalendarDay_Office2010Blue" savedcursor="[object Object]" style="cursor: pointer;">4</td>
```

I could select all of them using

```
By.cssSelector("[class^='dxeCalendarDay']");
```

> The class prefix   "*_Office2010Blue*"  will change at run time

But I need to **exclude elements** which having "*dxeCalendarOtherMonth...*"

probably something like.....

```
 By.cssSelector("[class^='dxeCalendarDay'].Not:([class*='dxeCalendarOtherMonth'])");
```

what is the correct syntax?

Comment: Also ..."_Office2010Blue" is subjects to change.

Comment: Do you have class Z in picture which you don't want to exclude?

Comment: with help of @Alexey R answer came up with `(By.cssSelector("[class^='dxeCalendarDay']:not([class*='dxeCalendarOtherMonth'])")`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assume you want to take all the elements having class `X` but having no class `Y`. Then your code will look like:

```
By.cssSelector(".x:not(.y)")
```

For example for the below html:

```
<div>
  <div class="x y">xy</div>
  <div class="x y z">xyz</div>
  <div class="x z">xz</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
</div>
```

The mentioned selector will select `xz` and `x`.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just select:

```
By.cssSelector('[class="X"]');
```

This will simply exclude the "Y" class objects without any NOT operators assuming there are NO "Z" class objects  in the picture.

Comment: yeah, simplicity is the key

Comment: Matching the class attribute is less robust than matching the class itself. `[class="X"]` would not match the perfectly valid attributes `class="X "` or `class="X Z"`, therefore it’s preferrable to use the built-in class matching: `.X` (combined with `:not(.Y)` in this case).

Comment: Your solution is simple and elegant...but doesn't work with _[class ^=X]_ which would not exclude "Y"

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is perhaps selecting class X straight away:

- `By.cssSelector("[class='dxeCalendarDay_Office2010Blue dxeCalendarOtherMonth_Office2010Blue']");`

Alternatively, you can go with select a class that ends with syntax:

- `By.cssSelector("[class$='dxeCalendarOtherMonth_Office2010Blue']");`

Comment: may be I'm not clear....so changed wordings. I need to exclude dxeCalendarOtherMonth